# How to automatically put the year?

Tags: php

I have a problem, I want that if I register student in the year 2016 it will then automatically put[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE9IU.png) the school_year(syearid) without clicking the select tag how to do it?

```
(school_year table has (syearid(pri), from_year,to_year))
```

from_year for example `2015` and to_year for example `2016`, if the year of the computer is 2016 then it will automatically put the school_year(syearid)

here's my code:

School Year

```
include('../connection/connect.php');
            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM school_year");
            $result->bindParam(':syearid', $res);
            $result->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                echo "<option value='".$row['syearid']."'>".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";
                }
            ?>
         </optgroup>
       </select>
```

Comment: Why is there the tag "javascript" on this question?

Comment: I'm sorry I though that javascript will be needed

Answer (score 2):

For HTML to pre-select an option it needs an `selected` attribute. 
Like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="d" selected>D</option>
</select>
```

Therefore, you can add the selected attribute in case `$row['to_year']` is equal to the current year on the server, `date("Y")` using something like this (untested):

`$isSelected = ((date("Y") == $row['from_year']) ? " selected" : "");`

`echo "<option value='".$row['syearid']."'$isSelected>".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `selected="selected"` to the option whose year should be selected. Then, add a condition to decide when to include that extra attribute, like so:

```
$currentYear = date('Y');

for ($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
    $selectedAttr = "";
    if ($row['from_year'] == $currentYear) {
        $selectedAttr = "selected=\"selected\"";
    }

    echo "<option value='".$row['syearid']."' ". $selectedAttr .">".$row['from_year'].'-'.$row['to_year']."</option>";
}
```

Please note that my condition assumes a check for `from_year` being equal to the current year. You may need to update this condition, if my understanding of your question was incorrect.

Comment: The function call on the first line should be `date`, not `data`